# Plugin Block at the backend of every page or post

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I need to show the plugin block element at the backend of every page or post. How can I  make that visible at the top or at the bottom of the editor similar to Yoast SEO plugin?

Comment: You mean like a meta box?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I am assuming you are talking about adding a meta box, similar to Yoast SEO's meta box...  if that IS the case, then try this:

```
//First, we add all the metaboxes we need...
//You can just repeat the `add_meta_box()` for each one 
function add_yournew_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box(
        'your_metabox_id',
        'The Title',
        'your_metabox_callback', //the next function below
        array(
            'post',
            'page'
        ),
        'normal',
        'high',
         array(
            '__block_editor_compatible_meta_box' => true,
            '__back_compat_meta_box'             => false,
        )
    );
}
//When we add a metabox we specify a callback function
//The third line in adding your metabox should match the name of this function
function your_metabox_callback( $post ) {
    //we want a unique nonce for security and to ensure only this post/page is updated
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'yourmetabox_nonce' );
    //put your metabox content in here
}
//When a user clicks 'Update/Publish', we want to make sure we're saving any data in the metaboxes
//This data will be saved as `post_meta`
function save_your_metabox_data( $post_id ) {
    //you'll have to run through any fields you put in the metabox and save them
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if( !isset( $_POST['yourmetabox_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['yourmetabox_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    //loop through all of your fields
    $yourmetabox_meta['one_of_your_fields']         = esc_textarea( $_POST['one_of_your_fields'] );
    $yourmetabox_meta['another_field']              = esc_textarea( $_POST['another_field'] );
    foreach( $yourmetabox_meta as $key => $value ) :
        if( 'revision' === $post->post_type ) {
            return;
        }
        if( get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, false ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value );
        } else {
            add_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $value);
        }
        if( !$value ) {
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, $key );
        }
    endforeach;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_your_metabox_data' );
```